# How to make inner box-shadow transparent on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make black ring which appears on hover to be transparent. but when i change `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 0 10px green` to   `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px transparent, 0 0 0 10px green` it not appearing. how do i achieve it?

```css
html { 
  background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*aoR-yl7jicuEvQ5hZoQvjw.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
div{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
div:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #000, 0 0 0 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: If it will be transparent then it will be green upto 10px

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a pseudo element **using position absolute** and **make that expand by 10 px** ( 5px for border and 5px for the gap) and then **add box shadow** and also you need to **add transition on the pseudo element** now instead of the element itself

```css
html { 
  background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*aoR-yl7jicuEvQ5hZoQvjw.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
div{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
div:after{
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;/* depends on your need change to 1 if want to overlap the div on hover*/
  top:-10px;
  bottom:-10px;
  left:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  transition:all 0.3s;
}
div:hover:after{
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so you can do this on this way but yes it is possible by using **pseudo element**

**for example**

```
div:after {
  content: "";
  bottom: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

div:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px green;
}
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*aoR-yl7jicuEvQ5hZoQvjw.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  bottom: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

div:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That effect will be different than the OP's as your effect will be fadeIn and OP's effect is like grow